# Python Regular expression don't mind spacing between letters

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a script in order to search for specific words in many PDF Documents with Python regex.

I have the problem that some words are not read in correctly and therefore do not lead to a match, e.g. I have stored the word "Extremalproblem" in the list of words to be searched for, but when the PDF is read in, the word appears as
"Extre malproblem" (space between e and m), which is why no match is created.

Other words are also read in incorrectly (with additional spacing where none actually belongs).
To be honest, I have no idea how I could ensure that a match is made when there is a space between the words I am looking for. So the match should happen quasi independently of word spacing. Is there an option?

```
# import packages
import PyPDF2
import re
import os, sys


dirs_list=[]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
    for name in dirs:
        dirs_list.append(dirs)

dirs_list=dirs_list[-1]
dirs_list.pop(0)


for k in dirs_list:
    data_names=os.listdir(k)
    data_names.pop(0)
    
    #counter=0
    for j in data_names:
        # open the pdf file
        reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(os.path.join(k, j))

        # define key terms
        strings = [['Grosses Einmaleins', 'Einmaleins'],
                   ['Extremwertprobleme', 'Extremalprobleme', 'Extremwerte','Optimierung', 'Optimierungsprobleme'], 

        
        total=len(strings)
        
        #print(total)

        counter=0
        # extract text and do the search
        for page in reader.pages:
            for i in strings:
                for s in i:
                    text = page.extract_text() 
                    print(text)
                    #re.IGNORECASE: Gross- und Kleinschreibung egal
                    res_search = re.search(s, text, re.IGNORECASE)
                    #print(res_search)

                    if res_search != None:
                        counter+=1
                        #Wort des Matchs löschen, dass er nicht mehrere Male gezählt wird.
                        #print(s)
                        strings.remove(i)
                        break
                    
        print(j, counter/total)
```

Comment: Are those words unique, I think a work around is try to remove all space in the text and search for those words, but it may give wrong result incase some other words make concate and appear as the same word we are searching for

Comment: A workaround: `r'\s?'.join(word)`. However, since they can't just be splitted anywhere in between, you'll need to come up with a better solution for this German-compound-noun problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Quick fix is to remove all the spaces

Replace

```
res_search = re.search(s, text, re.IGNORECASE)
```

with

```
res_search = re.search(s.replace(" ",""), text.replace(" ",""), re.IGNORECASE)
```

This should solve your stated problem.

It will, however, cause false-positive matches. For example, if you are searching for "car pet", and the web page contains "carpet", that will be a match. But if you can live with that limitation, it should do the job.